# How to make bash update its idea of hostname

Tags: bash, prompt

My bash prompt shows my hostname. If I change my hostname with the `hostname` command, in `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname` and `$HOSTNAME`, the prompt still uses the old name. Is it possible to update this without logging out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `\h` or `\H` in your prompt setting, its expansion is initialized when the shell starts, so you'll have to restart bash (`exec bash`). If that bothers you too much, change your prompt setting to print `$HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your bash prompt to update dynamically as the hostname (as reported by the `/bin/hostname` command) is updated, you can do this:

```
[root@foo ~]# PS1='[\u@`/bin/hostname` \W]\$ '
[root@foo ~]# hostname
foo
[root@foo ~]# hostname bar
[root@bar ~]# hostname baz
[root@baz ~]#
```

It's wasteful (runs a subshell every time you hit return -- not horrible but inelegant,) so I would only use this where the situation requires it. I use it when working on a base VM template that is used to generate multiple target VM instances where metadata about the instance is indicated in the hostname. And even then the custom `PS1` is only set temporarily, as part of the initial login session while the role VM instance is being deployed.